# Image downscale algorithm

Tags: image-processing

Is someone know which alogirhtm(s) Microsoft used in Paint to downscale picture?

I'm trying to develop a little software (for personnal use) to downscale a lot of pictures (in Java). After using the "builtin" java functions as NearestNeighbor, Bilinear and Bicubic, with poor result quality... I've used Lanczos algorithm which give far better results but without reaching MS Paint results :/

Note: Paint version used is the one of Windows 7, the Lanczos implementation I've used is the one of the Millie project [LanczosResamplePlugin.java](http://subversion.developpez.com/projets/Millie/trunk/MillieCoreFilter/src/millie/plugins/core/transform/LanczosResamplePlugin.java)
and the builtins java are from Graphics2D :

```
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE);
```

If someone have an idea to reach the same quality result, it will be helpfull (for my resulting pictures, and also for my knowledges).

Some results here:

(I'm not posting NN, bilinear and bicubic results which give really poor quality results)

Bellow a landscape (found on google image). Original file size is 1680x1050, and the grass is really sharpen in original file (so Paint result seems to be better than Lanczos).

Original image can be view here : [landscape-wallpaper-11a.jpg](http://iain.codejoust.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/landscape-wallpaper-11a.jpg)

Lanczos result:

[image: Lanczos landscape]

vs Paint Result:

[image: Paint landscape]

Another picture bellow (personnal picture), with some text. You can notice that in Lanczos result the text is less readable (less sharpen) than in Paint result. Moreover, between the black title text and the red area with white text, in Lanczos result there are some noise, which does not exist in Paint result. And at the bottom, the url on the paper is completly blur / unreadable on first result, and it's readable on Paint result.

Lanczos result:

[image: Lanczos cheese]

vs Paint Result:

[image: Paint chesse]

I'm firsly suppose that MS use 2 algorithms: 1 to downscale and a 2nd pass to sharpen the resulting picture? But as the bottom url in last example is still readable, it may be not resulting from a sharpening of downscaled result...?

Thanks

**Edit**

Ok, I'm a little bit stupid... the noise on pictures is due to jpeg compression quality (which I have no set in my Java code when saving picture).

Here below is the result in png, so witout noise. But result is still not readable as paint one.

Lanczos cheese png

[image: Lanczos cheese png]

Comment: Do you have links to the original images as well?

Comment: I've put the link of the first example original picture just above the result. For the second file, I have to found the way to upload and share it (file size is 3.5Mo).

Comment: Old mspaint does some big crap in downscaling. win 7 paint is definetly an improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I'm thinking I've got it!

In fact there are no magic in MS Paint (win7). It must used the well known Lanczos algorithm to resize image down (and up?), which seems to be the best general resampling algorithm (it seems that in XnView, in where we can choose the resampling algorithm, it's the default option).

So, I've found 2 other java implemtenations which each give differents results:

Original image : [landscape-wallpaper-11a.jpg](http://iain.codejoust.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/landscape-wallpaper-11a.jpg)

1. Lanczos from Milli project [here](http://subversion.developpez.com/projets/Millie/trunk/MillieCoreFilter/src/millie/plugins/core/transform/LanczosResamplePlugin.java)
   [image: landscape Lanczos 1]
2. Lanczos from "atyou" japanese blog [here](http://www.cnblogs.com/atyou/archive/2013/05/22/3092392.html)
   [image: landscape Lanczos 2]
3. Lanczos from "zattonaka" japanese blog [here](http://zattonaka.blogspot.fr/2012/10/java-lanczos.html)
   [image: landscape Lanczos 3]
4. Algo (Lanczos?) from MS Paint Win7
   [image: landscape MS Paint]

My second result set from one of my personnal picture:

1. From Milli project [here](http://subversion.developpez.com/projets/Millie/trunk/MillieCoreFilter/src/millie/plugins/core/transform/LanczosResamplePlugin.java)
   [image: cheese Lanczos 1]
2. From "atyou" japanese blog [here](http://www.cnblogs.com/atyou/archive/2013/05/22/3092392.html)
   [image: cheese Lanczos 2]
3. From "zattonaka" japanese blog [here](http://zattonaka.blogspot.fr/2012/10/java-lanczos.html)
   [image: cheese Lanczos 3]
4. Algo (Lanczos?) from MS Paint Win7
   [image: cheese MS Paint]

The result in item list 3 seems to be the closest one to Paint result (but not same). It have sharp well readable text (second test) and sharp grass as in original image (first test).

Moreovoer, as said before (edit part of my question), the noise was due to jpeg compression when saving. Results above here, are in PNG, and so do not suffer to jpeg artefact compression.

Comment: For good references to resizing filters and arguments for them, see ImageMagick pages at https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/ and https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/nicolas/

Answer (score 6):

MSPaint uses bilinear interpolation then sharpens the image with a convolution kernel:

0.0, -0.125, 0.0

-0.125, 1.5, -0.125

0.0, -0.125, 0.0

[ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) command:

```
magick image.png -scale 512 -morphology Convolve "3x3: 0.0, -0.125, 0.0 -0.125, 1.5, -0.125 0.0, -0.125, 0.0" image_resized.png
```

Comment: From what I can tell, this seems to be the most correct answer (`-scale`, and then convolve), or at least it is extremely close. There is one notable difference in how the smaller image dimension is being rounded though on proportional resizing - so for example if the limiting factor is the image height, then mspaint may sometimes produce an image whose width is 1px less than what ImageMagick produces. Wish I could +1 multiple times, I've been wondering about this for years!

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what Alex says, I'm pretty sure Paint uses the high quality bicubic method provided by GDI+ and it does **not** use an implementation like Zattonaka's. You can tell by asking both to reduce the size of an image of alternating black and white scan lines by one scan line.

In Paint, the black and white scan lines stay at the top and bottom but fade into dark grey in the middle.

Zattonaka's implementation keeps the alternating black and white scan lines throughout, but deletes one scan line. The cause is in this bit of code:

```
int bsx = (int)(dx / scale), bsy = (int)(dy / scale);
```

Although that gives good results on an artificial bar code image, what it's doing is essentially nearest-neighbour scaling with a Lanczos preprocessing stage bolted on. There are real-world images on which it will perform very poorly, for much the same reason that nearest-neighbour scaling doesn't work all that well: it tends to cut away small details. Thanks to the Lanczos convolution, Zattonaka's implementation isn't quite as bad as straight-up nearest neighbour, but some images still come out pretty awful.

If you're seeking something like what Paint does, it's probably best to try a good bicubic interpolator with pre-sharpening to counteract the downscaling blur. You might have to tweak it a little.